# electronにてwebpackでソースのビルドが成功しているのに何も表示されない

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron, babeljs

electron reactにてwebpackでソースのビルドが成功しているのに何も表示されない
いろいろ調べたりして直したのですがどこが間違っているのかどんどんわからなくなってきました
参考資料として「ソシム株式会社　いまどきJSプログラマーのための　Node.jsとReactアプリケーション開発テクニック」を読んでます

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

### main.js

```
const electron = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

// Electronのライフサイクルを定義
// メインウィンドウを表す変数
let mainWindow;
app.on("ready", createWindow);
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});
app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
});

// ウィンドウを作成してコンテンツを読み込む
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    //webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false },
  });
  // 読み込むコンテンツを指定
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
      protocol: "file",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );
  // ウィンドウが閉じる時の処理
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
```

### index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const { clipboard } = require("electron");

// コンポーネントを定義
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // 状態の初期化
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      isActive: false,
      zen2han: true,
    };
    // クリップボード監視用のタイマーをセット
    setInterval((e) => this.tick(), 1000);
  }
  // 全角英数を半角英数に変換する
  convToHalfWidth(str) {
    const s2 = str.replace(/[!-~]/g, (e) => {
      return String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(0) - 0xfee0);
    });
    return s2;
  }

  tick() {
    if (!this.state.isActive) return;
    const clip = clipboard.readText();
    let clip2 = clip;
    if (this.state.zen2han) {
      clip2 = this.convToHalfWidth(clip);
    }
    if (clip !== clip2) {
      clipboard.writeText(clip2);
    }
    this.setState({ text: clip });
  }

  changeState(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    this.setState({ [name]: !this.state[name] });
  }

  render() {
    const taStyle = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "300px",
      backgroundColor: "F4F4F4",
    };
    return (
      <div className="window">
        <div className="window-content">
          <div className="pane-group">
            <div className="pane-sm sidebar">
              <div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                  <li className="list-group-item">
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.isActive}
                        name="isActive"
                        onChange={(e) => this.changeState(e)}
                      />
                      監視を有効に
                    </label>
                  </li>
                  <li className="liat-group-item">
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.zen2han}
                        name="zen2han"
                        onChange={(e) => this.changeState(e)}
                      />
                      全角英数を半角に
                    </label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="pane">
              <div className="padded-more">
                クリップボード：
                <br />
                <textarea style={taStyle} value={this.state.text} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// domの書き換え
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

### index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>electron_fmt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/photon/dist/css/photon.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="out/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
var react = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
  .filter(function (x) {
    return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function (mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = "commonjs " + mod;
  });

module.exports = {
  // モード値を production に設定すると最適化された状態で、
  // development に設定するとソースマップ有効でJSファイルが出力される
  mode: "production",

  // メインとなるJavaScriptファイル（エントリーポイント）
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  target: "electron-main",
  // ファイルの出力設定
  output: {
    //  出力ファイルのディレクトリ名
    path: `${__dirname}/out`,
    // 出力ファイル名
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // 拡張子 .js の場合
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            // Babel を利用する
            loader: "babel-loader",
            // Babel のオプションを指定する
            options: {
              presets: [
                // プリセットを指定することで、ES2020 を ES5 に変換
                "@babel/preset-env",
                // React の JSX を解釈
                "@babel/react",
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  //externals: nodeModules,
};
```

### package.json

```
    "name": "electron_fmt",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "electron .",
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.11.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "electron": "^9.1.2",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "photon": "git+https://github.com/connors/photon.git",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "webpack": "^4.44.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
    }
}
```

Comment: 「何も表示されない」というのは、どういう状況ですか？　画面に何も出ないのですか、それとも空白のウィンドウが表示される(ウィンドウには何も表示されない)のですか？
「何も表示されない」状態の画面のスクリーンショットを質問に追加すると、よいかもしれません。

Comment: 「ビルドに成功している」はプログラムが文法的に間違っていないという事で、プログラムが作成者の意図どうりに動作することを保証している訳ではありませんよ。

Answer (score 1):

この本、持ってます。何ページのものですか？

require が定義されていない、というエラー表示が出ているみたいなので
何かビルド設定が間違っているのかも。

---

追記です。本の著者さんの記事が出ていました。

ちょうどエレクトロンのところですので、こちらで動かされるとよいと思います。

https://news.mynavi.jp/article/zerojavascript-6/

Comment: s.yamamotoさんコメントありがとうございます！
219~222pの内容です

Comment: すっかり忘れていました。調べてみます。

Comment: 先週から、すごく忙しくなってしまって何も試せなかったのですが、まだ同じところでつまっていたりしていますか？